# cordova image picker plugin for windows?

Tags: windows, cordova, plugins

i have used this image picker plugin for android and ios https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker. But it is not working for windows.

I have tried another plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera and used code like:

```
function addProfilePhoto() { 
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
    quality: 50, 
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM 
   //sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
}); 
function onSuccess(imageURI) {
  alert();
} 
function onFail(message) { 
  alert('Failed because: ' + message); 
}
```

Above code working fine with `sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA` but not with `sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM` or `sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY` it is coming back to index.html page not on the photo page.

Can any one suggest me any image picker plugin for windows app or any solution to above plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about the camera plugin with ```Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY``` or ```Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM```?

Comment: I have not tried these. let me try. Thanks

Comment: What windows platform are you targeting?  Windows 8, 8.1, or UWP (Windows 10)?

Comment: @MichaelPalermo i m targeting windows  8.1.

Comment: @jcesarmobile itried both. these are navigating to gallery but when coming back it is going to index page. For example i am on a page where i will pick image, but after picking image app is loading at index page.

Comment: or it's a bug or you are doing something wrong, show your code

Comment: @jcesarmobile I am having a multi page application, in which from index page i m going to pick an image page where on click of add picture function i have written this code:     
function addProfilePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {quality: 50,  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
    }); 
function onSuccess(imageURI) {alert();} 
function onFail(message) { alert('Failed because: ' + message);  }
After selecting image it is coming back to index.html instead of pick an image page.

Comment: file an issue on issues.cordova.io

Comment: @gavdix am facing same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Same issue here, come back to index.html instead of my photo page. Seems to be a plugin bug, hope someone would solve it

Comment: @Zappescu Have answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318074/cordova-app-navigates-to-home-screen-when-fetching-image-from-photolibrary/37436828#37436828

Comment: @Cody thank you, the single page transformation is not an option for us. Hope the bug will be soon solved