# Cordova app navigates to home screen when fetching image from PhotoLibrary

Tags: windows, cordova, camera

**Use Case**: Choose image from Gallery and execute callbacks

**Issue**: Redirection to Home screen of the app after image selection from Gallery.

Getting image from Camera works:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function() {
    console.log('success'); 
},function() {
    console.log('failure'); 
} , {
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
});
```

Choosing image from Gallery redirects to the homescreen

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function() {
    console.log('success'); 
},function() {
    console.log('failure'); 
} , {
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
});
```

The code is fairly simple and is mentioned at many places to give an example of how to choose image from Gallery. This code doesn't work on any screen other than the home screen of App. Also, no errors are reported before redirection.

The following code also results in redirection to the homescreen after image selection.

```
<input type="file" name="">
```

Configuration:

```
Device: Windows Lumia 535
Device OS Version: 8.1
Cordova: 6.1.1 
Cordova plugin camera: 2.2.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't able to stop the page navigation, unless on the first page of the app(without query parameters). Later, transformed the app to single page application thus avoiding this issue.

Issue can be tracked at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11295